# Find Maximum Date within Date Range without filtering in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a file with one row per EMID per Effective Date.  I need to find the maximum Effective date per EMID that occurred before a specific date.  For instance, if EMID =1 has 4 rows, one for 1/1/16, one for 10/1/16, one for 12/1/16, and one for 12/2/17, and I choose the date 1/1/17 as my specific date, I'd want to know that 12/1/16 is the maximum date for EMID=1 that occurred before 1/1/17.

I know how to find the maximum date overall by EMID (groupby.max()).  I also can filter the file to just dates before 1/1/17 and find the max of the remaining rows.  However, ultimately I need the last row before 1/1/17, and then all the rows following 1/1/17, so filtering out the rows that occur after the date isn't optimal, because then I have to do complicated joins to get them back in.

```
# Create dummy data
dummy = pd.DataFrame(columns=['EmID', 'EffectiveDate'])
dummy['EmID'] = [random.randint(1, 10000) for x in range(49999)]
dummy['EffectiveDate'] = [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2016,1,1), datetime.datetime(2018,1,3))) for i in range(49999)]

#Create group by 
g = dummy.groupby('EmID')['EffectiveDate']
# This doesn't work, but effectively shows what I'm trying to do
dummy['max_prestart'] = max(dt for dt in g if dt < datetime(2017,1,1))
```

I expect that output to be an additional column in my dataframe that has the maximum date that occurred before the specified date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `map` after selected .

```
s=dummy.loc[dummy.EffectiveDate>'2017-01-01'].groupby('EmID').EffectiveDate.max()
dummy['new']=dummy.EmID.map(s)
```

Here Using `transform`  and assuming  `else dt`

```
dummy['new']=dummy.loc[dummy.EffectiveDate>'2017-01-01'].groupby('EmID').EffectiveDate.transform('max')
dummy['new']=dummy['new'].fillna(dummy.EffectiveDate)
```